# Invitations to different Google Calendars within one account

Tags: google-calendar

Within my Google Calendar I have several different calendars set up.
Is it possible for someone else to send invitations directly to a specific calendar (not the default)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that something like this is currently possible with Google Calendars, and mainly because that functionality is not supported in the iCalendar format. What is possible is that you may move events between calendars in your account by editing the calendar details and choosing an different one from the drop down menu

Here is a link to a similar Stack Overflow question: [How to post calendar event to participant's specific calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406069/how-to-post-calendar-event-to-participants-specific-calendar),

Comment: It may not have been possible in 2011, but it is currently possible as long as the sender knows the ID of the calendar: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/70724/57964

Answer (score 14):

It is possible (even if the solution isn't nice). If the person knows the ID of your other calendar (which is a valid email address), he can send the invitation to the email address. The ID can be found in the settings of the calendar and has the form `...@group.calendar.google.com`.

There are however some drawbacks:

- The person who invites other people can choose the calendar on which this should appear, the guests can't change the calendar on which the event appears.
- The name of the guest is the name of the calendar. I use calendars with names like e.g. University, ... If I wanted someone to invite me to an event, and that event should be on my University calendar, only the name University would appear in the guest list. Now imagine five people want to have a meeting, and all of them want it to appear in their University calendar. Good luck figuring out who RSVP'd to the event.
- If you send an invitation to someone else in person, he normally gets an email telling him about that invitation. No such email is sent for a secondary calendar. The event just appears in the calendar.

Comment: Have you ever seen this work when the calendar invite actually comes via email from outside rather than just from another Google Calendar user? I tested it today and it doesn't seem to work.
Could be just a case of "no longer supported", but I'm wondering if perhaps this never worked from outside of Google…

Answer (score -1):

Another option, less ideal than @Misch, but avoids the pitfalls they mention, is to accept the invite, edit it, Copy to the desired calendar (move is disabled for invites) and delete the original.

FYI, this does "decline" the original, but gets your event to the correct cal.

Comment: Might this not delete the original event from everyone's calendars if you have "admin rights" on this event?