# Associate two email addresses (for invitations) with the same Google Calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, notifications, email-forwarding

I have a Gmail account `a@gmail.com` that is set up to send mails out of my work email account `a@example.com`. This works legitimately with Gmail's feature to **Send mail as:
(Use Gmail to send from your other email addresses)** in the **Accounts and Import** settings in Gmail.

**Problem:** sometimes people invite me to meetings via Google Calendar with the `a@example.com` account, whereas my Google Calendar (Google account) is set up in my `a@gmail.com`. I'm using Gmail features again (no forwarding): invitations sent there are *fetched* from `a@example.com`, that is, using the **Check email from other accounts:** feature to my Google mail (Gmail) account.

When I try to accept them, they give the following error:

> Google Calendar invitations cannot be forwarded via email. This event belongs to a@example.com and you are logged in as a@gmail.com. Please ask the meeting organiser to add you to the event from Google Calendar.

If Google is making it easy for me to fetch emails and send them from other aliases, how do I integrate that into the Calendar app?

One of the official answers at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/NZKP-Toxz-U indicates I should **create a separate account** for `a@example.com`, which defeats the purpose (I think) of  the Gmail *fetch* and *send email as* features. Is this just an example of inconsistency with feature-creep in Google's products?

Note: this question [Invitations to different Google Calendars within one account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/invitations-to-different-google-calendars-within-one-account) is not the same one I'm asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The instructions at http://www.tekgrl.com/accepting-google-calendar-invites-to-a-non-gmail-account/ worked for me, taking into the account the comments at the end. Here's a summary:

> Google has finally fixed this, all you have to do is enable a setting in your Google Calendar to be able to respond to any calendar invite sent to any of your Gmail alternate addresses. Here’s how you do it:
>
> 1. [from the comments] Set up the alternate email address `a@example.com` for your Google account. The option in Google Calendar below may not show up unless you have. [Here is Google’s help article for setting up alternate addresses](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/86635).
> 2. [from the comments] Wait some necessary time for the Google Calendar to recognize you've added the Alternate Email from step above.
> 3. In Google Calendar (on `a@gmail.com` account`) click the gear icon and choose Settings.
> 4. Select your primary calendar in the Calendars Configuration menu item on the left pane.
> 5. In the “General Notifications” section for your primary calendar, check the box “Allow me to respond to event invitations forwarded from these addresses.”

Note that invitations already sent before you set this up won't work. Only new invitations will work properly.

Comment: This won't work for Google Education or Business accounts, as they usually don't allow you to add alternate email addresses. (ie: This probably won't work for account that don't end in `@gmail.com`)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro does it mean those special Google domain don't allow fetching and sending emails from other domains? If so, then the problem won't exist (getting an invitation for the wrong account).

Comment: I don't see the “Allow me to respond to event invitations forwarded from these addresses.” box from the last step

Comment: Note that in the newest Google Calendar UI, this is under the "Settings for my calendars" header.

Comment: The option "Allow me to..." will not show up unless you add an alternate email address here: https://myaccount.google.com/alternateemail

Comment: Trying to respond to work invitation in my general email, but my work email is a Google Suite Education and I get this when I fallowed @niry's link "This setting can't be changed for your account."

Comment: @Pedro77 See the first comment here from stevoisiak