# How to accept calendar invite that automatically forwarded to my on the original primary google account?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have two accounts:

a@gmail.com

b@gmail.com

All emails sent to a@gmail.com automatically forwarded to b@gmail.com

Now. when I see a calendar invite in b@gmail.com and accept it, I want that who sent the invite will see that a@gmail.com accepted it (he don't know that I'm using b@gmail.com)

I have tried to created a shared calendar, so when I accept it on b@gmail.com, I see it on a@gmail.com.

Anyway I want to not confuse my hosts, and that they will see that a@gmail.com did it?

How can I do it? Any solution is acceptable (If it's not built-in in Google, Maybe using App-script, Chrome extension, or who knows)

I have read this: [How can I respond to Google Calendar invitations from my alternate email?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108850/how-can-i-respond-to-google-calendar-invitations-from-my-alternate-email) but it's seems not what I'm looking for.

Also: [Associate two email addresses (for invitations) with the same Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99912/associate-two-email-addresses-for-invitations-with-the-same-google-calendar) but it seems since the second account is on gmail I can't make it alternative email address.

Answer (score 1):

The email will have two parts. The "magic widget" above with some buttons to quickly answer, and the real body below starting with "You have been invited to the following event". If you click on the Yes button above b@gmail.co will be answering, but below there should be a text like "Going (a@gmail.com)?" with a Yes link. Clicking on this link will open the right calendar and accept the event. It's just not as convenient.