# Google calendar moving invite

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I'm trying to do a few things with Google Calendar and can't get one thing right:

I have many calendars defined (for better organization).

For example I have one named "Training" with a nice red color.

Whenever I'm getting an invite to my gmail address, the event is being pushed into my "main" calendar, and I can't move it to my "Training" calendar.

For the organizer this won't make any difference, only to me keeping myself organized.

How can I move an invite to my "Training" calendar?

The trick here is to actually *move* the invite! I know I can *copy* the event to my "Training" calendar, but I wish to keep all invites, and details. Technically I wish a sender to send his invite to my "Training" calendar. How am I supposed to do this?

Please check this:

[image]

Comment: You cannot if you are not the organizer or have editing rights for the organizer's calendar.  There are some hacks apparently that would require the engagement of the original sender.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406069/how-to-post-calendar-event-to-participants-specific-calendar and https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18588/invitations-to-different-google-calendars-within-one-account/109247#109247